# What is proper way to handle when users TEMP directory is full (65535 items)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My application uses temporary files for some operations.

I'm using [Path.GetTempFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It says that it will fail if there are too many files in temp directory.

From my knowledge Temp directory is not cleaned by Windows. What is the best way to handle scenario when user has too many files in Temp directory?

Is there any pattern for that?

Comment: What it actually say is it fails it you use the function to create more than 64k files; this probably means that those files are created with a counter in the name which then overflows. Other files with other names do not matter. If you create so many files (smell, smell) you should clean them up! - You can get a GUID and use it instead.

Comment: @TaW I need to create only few files. But I was worried about other apps (no mine) that can fill Temp Directory. I think I'll use guid method and manualy create file.

Comment: If you manually create your temporary files, consider passing the `FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag. That way you don't have to worry about cleaning up. It happens automatically, when you close those files. They are also cleaned up in case your application crashes or is forcefully closed.